# Passport deserializeUser() is never called with Axios http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, axios

When I send a request via axios to my Express app, req.isAuthenticated() is always false and req.user does not exist, even after logging in. But when I send a request via Postman to the app, it works. It seems that deserializeUser() is never called so the req.session.passport field is never populated.

I've tried all of the suggestions online, any help is appreciated.

External request:

```
async tweet(content) {
    try {
      await axios.post(this.url + '/tweets/new', {
        content: content,
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      });

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

index.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)
const redisCookie = require('heroku-redis-client');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

// required for passport
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  // secret: process.env.SECRET || 'enteryoursecrethere',
  secret: 'enteryoursecrethere',
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 },
  resave: true,
  store: new RedisStore({client: redisCookie.createClient()}),
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

router.js

```
var tweets = require('../controllers/tweets');
var router = express.Router();
var isLoggedIn = require('../middleware/isLoggedIn');

router.post('/tweets/new', isLoggedIn, tweets.tweet);
```

middleware/isLoggedIn.js

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    // If user is authenticated in the session, carry on.
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      next();
      return
    }

    // If they aren't redirect them to the home page.
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models').User;
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  // The login request establishes a session maintained in a browser cookie.
  // Requests after the login request not contain credentials,
  // but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session. The user object
  // is constructed to and from the ID in the cookie.

  // Converts user to user id.
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // Converts user id to user, stored in req.user.
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id).then(function(user) {
      done(null, user);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
  });

  /* ============Login============ */
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // Send entire request for flash message.
  }, loginCallback));

  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
  }, signupCallback));

};

function loginCallback(req, username, password, done) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return done(null, req.user);
  }
  // Look up the user by username.
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      username: username
    }
  }).then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginUsernameMessage', 'Wrong username.'));
    }

    if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginPasswordMessage', 'Wrong password.'));
    }

    return done(null, user.get());
  }).catch(function(err) {
    return done(err);
  });
}

function signupCallback(req, username, password, done) {
  // Asynchronous. User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back.
  process.nextTick(function() {
    if (password != req.body.password_confirm) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Passwords don\'t match.'));
    }

    // Find a user whose email is the same as the forms email.
    // We are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists.
    User.findOne({
      where: {
        [Sequelize.Op.or]: [ { username: username }, { email: req.body.email }]
      }
    }).then(function(user) {
      // Check to see if theres already a user with that username or email.
      if (user) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email or username is already taken.'));
      }
      // Create the user.
      var data = {
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname,
        username: username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: User.generateHash(password)
      }

      User.create(data).then(function(newUser) {
        return done(null, newUser);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        return done(err);
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      return done(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works only with postman because the session is being set at the server(express) but not at the client(axios).

So when you request from axios, It doesn't know if the session is already set at the server. So you need to send the credentials origin along with the request. Modify your request like this:

```
await axios.post(this.url + '/tweets/new', {
    content: content,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: "same-origin"
  });
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/244) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This didn't fix the issue, so any other suggestions would be appreciated. Do you know why passport.deserializeUser() is never called when sending the request via Axios?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a year old now but I had a heck of a time solving this problem using Node/Express/Passport/React with a local-strategy and express-session.

For me, adding this to the header:

```
withCredentials:true
```

wasn't enough. That *did* trigger a CORS problem but did not actually make axios send the session cookie with the request.

This causes a situation where the login would create a session, but the deserialize function would never be called and req.user would always be empty.

This is what fixed the issue:

In my React component constructor I added this line of code:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

That fixed it.

In fact, it fixed it so well that I was able to remove all other headers in Axios. Everything just started working.

Figuring this out took me a solid two hours today, I hope this answer helps someone.